# d3.js: Unusual Error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this d3.js project donut chart. For some reason, I am not able to access the data with in the `onmousemove`. The `i` value become zero is all the functions I pass within that event. I want to access the data of the particular slice where the mouse has moved.

How do I resolve this? Someone pls hlp!

Here is my code so far:

```
piesvg.selectAll("path")
.data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
.attr('class', 'slice')

 var slice = d3.selectAll('g.slice')
  .append('path')
  .each(function(d) {
    d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20;
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colorspie(i)
  })
  .on("mouseover", arcTween(outerRadius, 0))
  .on("mouseout", arcTween(outerRadius - 20, 150)) 
  .on("mousemove", function(data){
    piesvg.select(".text-tooltip")
     .attr("fill", function(d,i){return colorspie(i)})
     .text(function(d, i){return d[i].domain + ":" + parseInt(d[i].value * 20)}); //Considers i as 0, so no matter whichever slice the mouse is on, the data of only first one is shown
  });
```

Here is the full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/QuikProBro/xveyLfyd/1/

I dont know how to add external files in js fiddle so it doesn't work....

Here is the .tsv that is missing:

```
value   domain
1.3038675   Cloud
2.2541437   Networking
0.15469614  Security
0.8287293   Storage
0.7292818   Analytics
0.61878455  Intelligence
1.7016574   Infra
0.4088398   Platform
```

Comment: can you give a working fiddle of your code

Comment: I have put the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/QuikProBro/xveyLfyd/1/ 
I don't know how to add external .tsv files in fiddle.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your piesvg.select is bound to be zero-indexed for i and in all probability undefined for d as it takes those values from a single tooltip element, not the slices. Hard to be 100% sure from the snippet, but I suspect you're wanting to access and use the 'data' and 'i' from the original selectAll on the slices.

```
.on("mousemove", function(d, i){
    piesvg.select(".text-tooltip")
     .attr("fill", colorspie(i))
     .text(d.data.domain + ":" + parseInt(d.data.value * 20));   
});
```

Edited as pie slices store original data in d.data property ^^^

Comment: Adding data does not work, could you tell me what other information you're looking for so that I can update this?

Comment: I mean replacing `d` with `data`

Comment: Did you try the code snippet as above? If that doesn't work you'll

Comment: Whoops... Need to add a jsfiddle as Cyril asks so people can have a poke about rather than just eyeballing your code

Comment: Hi, please check I have updated the question. The filldle doesnt work because I could not add my external data file there. Sorry for that...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xveyLfyd/3/ - There, the original values are in d.date and you still had to remove the function(d,i) from the text setting codea - PS arcTween is missing so I had to comment a couple of lines out